# I have to redirect the page based on location of the page. May i know which method is best practice

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
lifecycleMethodName (){ const presentPage = 'home/page1';if (this.props.location!==presentPage){this.pros.redirectTo(presentPage);}}
```

FYI. I have tried component will receive props and component did update but no luck. can some one help me ?

Comment: Are you using react router?

Comment: If yes, then you can create wrapper for router, check this example https://gist.github.com/kud/6b722de9238496663031dbacd0412e9d#file-privateroute-js

Answer (score 0):

Use it in this way :-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = () => {
  constructor(props){
   this.state={
    isRedirect : false,
    presentPage : "home/page1"
 }
}
  const renderRedirect = () => {
  if (this.state.isRedirect && this.props.location!==this.state.presentPage) {
    return (
     <Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/home/page1'
     }}
    />
   );
 }
}

  const clicked = () => {
    console.log('clicked');
    this.setState({
     isRedirect :true
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Home
       {renderRedirect()} 
      <button onClick={() => clicked()}>click</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Or you want use lifeCycle method then call `clicked()` function in `componentDidMount` like below:-

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.clicked()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common use case. The React life cycle method you're looking for is `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount (){ <<your code to redirect >>}
```

The above will trigger when the component is mounted. It will also work for server-side rendered components since the method only runs clientside.

However if your app is client-side only and your component is a `Class` component you can also run your code in the constructor itself, since it will have access to the props.

If you're in a function component, you can run it inside the component right away, there's no need to use any hook, since the function will have access to the props right away.